# Скрипт для преобразования символов

Tags: кодировка, php

У меня в базе mysql все содержимое в html entities. Я написал скрипт, который должен преобразовать все в символы кодировки utf 8, но не работает. Подскажите, почему?

```
 <?php
  $decoder = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM work");
  $unirow = mysql_fetch_array($decoder);

  do{
    $id = $unirow['id'];
    $name1 = $unirow['name1'];
    $name2 = $unirow['name2'];
    $adress = $unirow['adress'];
    $tel = $unirow['tel'];
    $note = $unirow['note'];
    mb_convert_encoding($name1, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8"); 
    mb_convert_encoding($name2, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    mb_convert_encoding($adress, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    mb_convert_encoding($tel, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    mb_convert_encoding($note, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    mysql_query("UPDATE aro SET name1='$name1',name2='$name2',adress='$adress',tel='$tel',note='$note' WHERE id='$id'");      
  }
  while($unirow = mysql_fetch_array($decoder));            
  ?>
```

Comment: а как именно не работает?

Comment: я ж вам в предыдущем вопросе приводил полную функцию, не понравилась?)

Comment: это не сработало((

Comment: в базе ничего не меняется

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вам нужно преобразовать БД в другую кодировку. А если не использовать PHP? Поступить, например, как вот тут описано: [перекодирование MySQL базы из Latin1 в UTF-8](http://dev-4-web.ru/change-mysql-encoding-from-latin1-to-utf8). Ну, или если не хотите переходить по ссылке, то просто сделать пару запросов:

Это если столбцы хранятся в кодировке по умолчанию (которая указана в конфиге mysql)

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

А это нужно выполнить для каждого столбца c1 (если кодировка не та, что в конфиге):

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 BLOB;    
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

На всякий случай рекомендую базу забекапить. )

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, работать не будет.

```
string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding ] )
```

Т.е надо

```
mb_convert_encoding($name1, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
```

Comment: ничего не меняется.....Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему...

Comment: Попробуйте функцию - html_entity_decode($str)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $decoder = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM work");

while($unirow = mysql_fetch_array($decoder))
{
    $id = $unirow['id'];
    $name1  = mb_convert_encoding($unirow['name1'],  "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    $name2  = mb_convert_encoding($unirow['name2'],  "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    $adress = mb_convert_encoding($unirow['adress'], "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    $tel    = mb_convert_encoding($unirow['tel'],    "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    $note   = mb_convert_encoding($unirow['note'],   "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");

    mysql_query("UPDATE aro SET     name1='$name1',name2='$name2',adress='$adress',tel='$tel',note='$note' WHERE id='$id'");

}

?>
```

Comment: Черт с ним уже все! Не получается.

Comment: ты о чем ? Попробуй исправленный мною скрипт..

Comment: не получается,ничего не меняется....